# trouble printing the element that comes first in the lexicographical ordering of the array of strings (java)

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have to read 10 strings from the keyboard and then save them into a array of strings and finally I need to print the string that comes first relative to a lexicographical ordering of the strings. I'm having trouble with the last part? Any suggestions to what I'm doing wrong?

```
int size = 10;
int count = 0;
String[] words = new String[size];

Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter 10 digits: ");
while (count < size) {
    words[count] = keyboard.next();
    count++;
}
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    if (words[i].compareTo(words[i + 1]) > 0) {
        String biggest = words[i];

        System.out.println(biggest);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the smallest (first in the lexographical ordering), you would do:

```
String smallest = null;

for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
        smallest = words[i];
    } else if (words[i].compareTo(smallest) < 0) {
        smallest = words[i]
    }
}

System.out.println(smallest);
```

Or, by converting the array to a list and using the [`Collections`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) utility class:

```
String smallest = Collections.min(Arrays.asList(words));
```

Or, by sorting the array and getting the first value:

```
Arrays.sort(words);
String smallest = words[0];
```

Comment: ...or sorting the array and picking the last element - many ways to skin this cat.

Comment: but wait i got a question ? the code runs but i want it to print the word or element that comes first in the lexicographical order ?

Comment: So smallest instead of biggest?

Comment: well like it needs to print the first word just like in a dictionary . for example if you have (mike, aaaa, dave, ccc)

Comment: then it would need to print "aaa" since its the first one